# Using prime numbers to generate a random password

Tags: python, security, scripting, numbers

I'm doing a college project which started off with printing out all the prime numbers between two given inputs. I was later told that it had to be somewhat relevant to my course, Network Management, so I wanted to add a password generator onto the end of my script(for network security)

I have all the code written out but I have a problem with it not being able to use a random prime number in the list I have printed out. It only uses the last number printed and I understand why but is there anyway I can make it so that does use a random prime number or will I have to store the numbers somewhere?

```
#A program to count the prime numbers from a given start to a given end


#importing math function
import math
import os, random, string
#Input the number to start counting from
Starting_number = input("Enter the starting number: ")




#Input the number to end the count on.
Ending_number = input("Enter the number you want to count up to: ")

#if Starting_number is less than 0 it will print out a suitable message.
if Starting_number < 0:
    print 'Invalid entry, please enter a positiv number. \nWill count from ',Starting_number, 'to 0 and begin prime number count to',Ending_number, '.'

#If Ending_number is less than or equals to 0 then it will print out a suitable message.
if Ending_number <= 0:
    print 'Invalid entry on last input \nPlease enter two positive numbers for the count to work.'

#Starting loop as long as the current count is between Starting_number and Ending_number
for num in range(Starting_number, Ending_number):

    #
    if all(num%i !=0 for i in range(2,num)):

        print num





if num >= 1 and num <= 100:
    length = 4
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
    random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

    print ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))


if num >= 101 and num <= 200:
    length = (Ending_number / Starting_number) * 5 + 11
    if length >= num:
        length = num / 100
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
    random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

    print ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
```

Comment: Avoid `input` in python2. It does *not* take numbers as input. It *executes* python code. If you try to input `[1,2,3]` when you are prompted for the starting number you'll see an error you don't expect. Also the user could insert things like `__import__("os").system("kill my machine command")` and really bad things could happen. To request an integer simply use `int(raw_input(...))`. Or `float(raw_input(...))` for floating point numbers. In python3 the function called `input` is actually `raw_input`, hence you'd have to add the `int(..)` call anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you detect prime numbers add them to a list.

Instead of just

```
print num
```

add it to a list like so:

```
primes.append(num)
```

then you can select a random item from your 'primes' list:

```
from random import choice
print choice(primes)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted to add this as a comment but I do not have enough credits to add a comment. For password generator, you do not want it to be a prime number. You should just randomly choose a number. If you have a 32 bit number, you have more entropy if the number is randomly in the full 32-bit space. If you limit it to only prime numbers, you have considerably reduced the space. Not directly related to what you are asking but it may be useful to know.